# Hibernate HQL IN clause only match first item of list

Tags: hibernate, hql

The problem : IN clause of hql query matches only first item of a comma separated list!

The HQL query is like this : `from News where 93 IN (pictureIds)`

News entity is :

```
public class News {
  String id;
  String pictureIds; // comma separated list of pictureIds
}
```

NOTE: if I change HQL query and hardcode the pictureIds its result is correct!

How can I change my query to resolve the problem?

Comment: are you using hibernate template to do so..??

Comment: I'm using Hibernate, Criteria and Criterion to build HQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from News where pictureIds LIKE '%,93,%'
```

Commas added to the start and the end.

Comment: At last I decided to change database structure.

Comment: LIKE '%93%' matches not only 93 but also 9393 and 3493 and so on.

Comment: You could add a comma at the beginning and the end and match `%,93,%`.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger and what happens if 93 is first or last element?

Comment: @OptimusPrime True, to be complete it should be: `pictureIds LIKE '%,93,%' OR pictureIds LIKE '93,%' OR pictureIds LIKE '%,93 OR pictureIds = '93'`. Sidenote: I didn't change the answer, I only put a comment. **It's always dangerous to 'fix' answers. If it's not the same solution anymore, it should be a different answer or only a comment.** Note: the answer was accepted *before* it was changed again.

Comment: You can add this under Update: heading. Let the original one be as is.

Answer (score 0):

**This will do.**

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery("Select * from News where pictureIds In (:List)")  
             .setParameterList("List",ListValues);
```

Look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm) for basics of HQL usage.

Answer (score 0):

I have got it to work but its rather tedious:

```
results?.eachWithIndex { output, i->
                    if (i>0) {
                        sb.append(" or ")
                    }
                    sb.append(" ((dbres.Field like (:myVariablesA${i})) or (dbres.Field like (:myVariablesB${i})) or (dbres.Field like (:myVariablesC${i})) or dbres.Field=:myVariable${i})")
                    //capture within csv so aa,val,bb
                    myParams."myVariablesA${i}"='%,'+output+',%'
                    //capture as last element: aa,val
                    myParams."myVariablesB${i}"='%,'+output
                    //capture it as first element val,aa
                    myParams."myVariablesC${i}"=output+',%'
                    //finally capture it if its not a csv and its a physical set value
                    myParams."myVariable${i}"=output
                }
```

This is in groovy and is appending to a StringBuilder (sb) element. In short the  %,id,% on its own for a csv string field is too strong . By adding all the variations comma before after and on its own captures all variations that could exist in the actual string

Hope it helps someone else